# Trying to get the value of an element or itself inside some element in Json returns null

Tags: java, json, element, gson

Hello Im trying to get the value of an element from a JsonObject. i'm using java with the
Gson library.

here is the related part of the code:

```
String s = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=30.065634,31.209473&destination=29.984177,31.440052&sensor=false";
URL url = new URL(s);

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    ((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()).getInputStream()));

JsonStreamParser jsp = new JsonStreamParser(r);

JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();

JsonElement jsonElement =  jp.parse(r);

JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

System.out.println(jsonObject.get("summary"));
```

here is a part of the Json:

```
"status": "OK",   "routes": [ {
    "summary": "Mehwar Al Moneeb",
    "legs": [ {
      "steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 30.0655100,
          "lng": 31.2096600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 30.0654400,
          "lng": 31.2096000
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "mdovDksn}DLJ",
          "levels": "BB"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 1,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003esouthwest\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eOmar Toson\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eMohammed Roshdi\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 9,
          "text": "9 m"
        }
      }
```

When I get the top element "routes" its fine and printing it displays what inside the element but when I try to for example to get the element "summary" as shown, the return is null, thats whats is displayed in the output, so subsequently I cannot get the value of it. 
Whats wrong? how can get the value of any JsonElement? Please reply back to me as soon as you can. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes is a javascript array.  Summary is a property of the first object in that array, so you need to use `jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("routes").get(0).get("summary");` or equivalent. I haven't worked with your Java library, but the JS code would be `jsonObject.routes[0].summary`

Edit: Looked up [GSON Documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) and updated code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think i got it. you first get the  jsonObject of the json file then get the top element as an array and in order to get the element inside you have to first get it as a Json object then get it as array by providing the name of the element and so forth...